# Platform Events in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, platform-event

I want to add a platform event to my managed package, however since platform events are not supported in professional edition, it will break the installation of the package in professional edition.

Is there a way to selectively deploy the package components based on edition?

Should I be using metadata API to create the platform event after the package is installed?

Comment: No. The linked answer provides no solution, only confirms the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to selectively deploy the package components based on edition?

No. Managed packages are a "black box", everything or nothing gets installed.

> Should I be using metadata API to create the platform event after the package is installed?

I wouldn't recommend it; you will make using your package very problematic. Instead, if you are working on 2GP managed packages:

1. create two separate packages, let's call them "core" and "event"
2. make "event" depend on "core"
3. have them both in the same namespace and use [@NamespaceAccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_NamespaceAccessible.htm) for items in "core" that "event" needs to access.
4. put all the platform event related stuff in the "event" package

When a customer only has professional edition they just install "core". However, if they have enterprise or other edition they install first "core" then "event", allowing them to make use of your new functionality that uses platform events.